# Importing module from python package

Tags: python, package

I have package in following structure

```
Main_file 
     __init__.py
     main.py
     sub_folder
          __init.py
          a.py
          b.py
```

## b.py contain

```
def print_value():
    print("hello")
```

## a.py contain

```
import b
b.print_value()
```

## in  main.py

```
from sub_folder import a
```

## when i run main.py i got following error

```
No module named 'b'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sub_folder` is not in your `PYTHONPATH`, you need to use a [relative import](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#relative-imports) from `a.py`:

```
from . import b
b.print_value()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also include the `sub_folder` into the system path by

```
import sys
sys.path.append(<path to sub_folder>)
```

Note: as observed in the comments below, this can create issues due to double loads. This works for scripts, and is not the right method to use when writing packages.

Comment: The result of that would be having two versions of each module: there would be module `a` **and** module `sub_folder.a`, with same contents, but treated by Python as two separate modules. Sometimes it does not matter, when you encounter bugs caused by this, they will be rather ugly bugs ;)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I was thinking from the point of view of writing a script, rather than a package!